# How to define level of depth in recursion function that builds binary tree?

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, tree

I have a persons table in mysql db, every person has mother and father, so I need to build the inheritance tree and I have a function for that, if just run it, it works fine, but I need to define the depth of inheritance tree, I made reference variable for that, it counts the recursion well but there is another problem, it makes tree only for mother line, if I switch 'if' statements it will build only father tree, how can I make it work or maybe there is another way to do it?

```
public function makeTree(array &$rootPerson, &$quantity = 14)
{
    if ($quantity < 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($rootPerson['mother_id'])) {
        $rootPerson['parents']['mother'] = $this->getPerson($rootPerson['mother_id']);
        $this->makeTree($rootPerson['parents']['mother'], --$quantity);
    }

    if (isset($rootPerson['father_id'])) {
        $rootPerson['parents']['father'] = $this->getPerson($rootPerson['father_id']);
        $this->makeTree($rootPerson['parents']['father'], --$quantity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion follows the first part all the way down to `$quantity === -1` and then `$quantity` will be the same value no matter what level **because you did this by reference**. If you change it so that each iteration has it's own version and that you only decrease it once you are there:

```
public function makeTree(array &$rootPerson, $quantity = 14)
{
    if ($quantity < 0) {
        return;
    }

    $quantity--;

    if (isset($rootPerson['mother_id'])) {
        $rootPerson['parents']['mother'] = $this->getPerson($rootPerson['mother_id']);
        $this->makeTree($rootPerson['parents']['mother'], $quantity);
    }

    if (isset($rootPerson['father_id'])) {
        $rootPerson['parents']['father'] = $this->getPerson($rootPerson['father_id']);
        $this->makeTree($rootPerson['parents']['father'], $quantity);
    }
}
```